# Can the vibration intensity be changed for the Samsung Galaxy J3?

Tags: samsung, vibration

I am trying to maximize the vibration intensity on my Samsung Galaxy J3. I can change the vibration pattern, but I cannot find the setting to change the vibration intensity.

Is there an inherent limitation for the J3 or am I missing something?

The model number is SM-J320W8 and the phone is running Android 7.1.1 with Samsung Experience Version 8.5.

I did a quick Ctrl-F search in the manual, but couldn't find anything.
Manual:  [SM-J320W8 Manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201611/20161110224254910/SM-J320W8_UG_EN5.pdf)

Here is a screenshot of my settings page:
[image: Screenshot of Sound and Vibrations Settings Page]